# Wrap a method to wait for callback

Tags: c#, delegates, async-await

I have client code (ViewModeL) that is calling a `ConnectedThingService` that is calling a `CoapService` to update the mode on a "thing". The update method on the `CoapService` returns a task and has parameters for success and error responses.

````
Task<Task> SetModeFrom(DeviceModel Device, CoAPResponseReceivedHandler responseHandler, CoAPErrorHandler errorHandler);```
````

CoAPResponseRecivedHandler and CoAPErrorHandler are delegates.

Here is the code that calls the CoapService:

```
public async Task<ApiResponse> UpdateModeAsync(int mode)
{
    ApiResponse result = new ApiResponse();
    await _coapService.SetControlModeFromCombo(device, (updateResp) =>
    {
        if (updateResp.Code.Value != CoAPMessageCode.CONTENT)
        {
            result.IsSuccessful = false;
            result.ErrorMessages.Add("Failed setting mode");
        }
        else
        {
            var coapResponse = 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ControlModel>(updateResp.GetPayload());
            result.IsSuccessful = true;
            Mode = mode;
        }
    }, (e, associatedMsg) =>
    {
        result.IsSuccessful = false;
        result.ErrorMessages.Add("Failed setting mode");
    }); 
    return result;
```

The problem is the call is returning before either of the delegates are firing and therefore I'm always returning false (the default) in the ApiResponse. Is there a way to make this call and wait for either of the 2 delegates to get called before returning back to the client, and do so in a way that is not blocking? And is it possible to have a timeout so that if neither of the 2 delegates fire after a timeout period, it returns false?

Edit: I inherited this code. The lowest level code is from CoAPSharp.com. Here is the code for SetControlModeFromCombo:

```
public async Task<Task> SetControlModeFromCombo(DeviceModel Device, 
CoAPResponseReceivedHandler responseHandler, CoAPErrorHandler 
errorHandler)
{
    ushort msgID = Convert.ToUInt16(new Random().Next(1000, 9999));
    var task = new TaskCompletionSource<DeviceModel>();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Device.CODE))
    {
        var controlSettings = new ControlModel()
        {
            Mode = Device.ComboSettings.Mode,
        };
        await _coap.MakeRequest(Device.CODE, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(controlSettings.ControlMode()), Device.IPADDRESS, ControlModel.Endpoint, CoAPMessageType.CON, CoAPMessageCode.PUT, msgID, (CoAPResponse response) =>
        {
            responseHandler(response);
            task.SetResult(Device);
        }, (Exception e, AbstractCoAPMessage associatedMsg) =>
        {
            errorHandler(e, associatedMsg);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        ThrowMissingCodeError(task);
    }
    return task.Task;
}
```

And here is the MakeRequest Method:

```
public async Task MakeRequest(string token, string outboundIP, string uri, byte type, byte code, ushort id, CoAPResponseReceivedHandler responseHandler, CoAPErrorHandler errorHandler)
{
    try
    {
        _coapClient = new CoAPClientChannel();
        await _coapClient.Initialize(outboundIP, _outboundPort);
        _coapClient.CoAPResponseReceived += responseHandler;
        _coapClient.CoAPError += errorHandler;
        await _coapClient.Send(AssembleRequest(type, code, id, outboundIP, uri, token), outboundIP);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: It depends on how `SetControlModeFromCombo` works. Can you show it?

Comment: It's extremely weird to have a method that returns a task *and* has delegate callbacks. How are you supposed to know when it's done?

Comment: @StephenCleary That's the problem. The code currently has the delegates going all the way back up to the ViewModel. I'm having to work within the design of CoAPSharp code.